# Flutter - I can't change the state of a static method of onWillPop

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bottomNavigatorBar in my app, and on some screens I don't make it visible, so create a static method to handle it from any class. it works, but when I use the instance of this static method in onWillPop I have the following problems...

```
E/flutter (10927): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called in constructor: _telaPrincipalState#cb9c4(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
E/flutter (10927): This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created
```

**I already used mounted, but it still didn't work**

if(!this.mounted){

}

**Here is the 3 page code where I use routes**

```
class AtivarEmailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String route = "/ativarEmail";

  @override
  _AtivarEmailPageState createState() => _AtivarEmailPageState();
}

class _AtivarEmailPageState extends State<AtivarEmailPage> {
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        if (!mounted) {
          setState(() => telaPrincipal.show());
        }

        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            HomeView.route, (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
            arguments: null);
      },
      child: Scaffold(code...),);
  }
}
```

**the problem happens when I call onWillpop to return to HomeView**

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String route = "/";

  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {

Widget home(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(code..);
  }
}
```

**the bottomNavigatorBar manipulated by the static method is in the code below. It is the screen that is under the whole stack, so the navigation bar is floating on top of the other pages**

```
class telaPrincipal extends StatefulWidget {
  telaPrincipal({this.categoria, this.exercicio});
  static _telaPrincipalState tela = _telaPrincipalState();

  @override
  _telaPrincipalState createState() {
    return tela;
  }

  static indexBar(int index) {
    tela.onItemTapped(index);
  }

  static void hide() {
    tela.hideNavBar();
  }

  static void show() {
    print("show");
    tela.showNavBar();
  }
}

class _telaPrincipalState extends State<telaPrincipal> {
  void hideNavBar() {
    setState(() {
      _show = false;
      _bottomBarHeight = 0;
    });
  }

  void showNavBar() {
    setState(() {
      _show = true;
      _bottomBarHeight = 60;
    });
  }

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

//bottomNavigatorBar routes
  final pagesRouteFactories = {
    HomeView.route: () => MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeView()),
    programaTreino.route: () => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => programaTreino(
              exercicioEscolhido: null,
              categoria: null,
            )),
    pesquisar_view.route: () =>
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pesquisar_view()),
  };

  bool _show = true;
  double _bottomBarHeight = 60;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: HexColor("#121212"),
            body: _buildBody(),
            bottomNavigationBar: Container(
              height: _bottomBarHeight,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: _show
                  ? _buildBottomNavigationBar(context)
                  : Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    ),
            )),
      ),
      onWillPop: () async {
        navigatorKey.currentState.maybePop();
        return false;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() => MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        String routeName = settings.name;

        //Map<String, dynamic> args = route.arguments;  // Get any arguments passed to the route
        print("ongenate$routeName}");
        switch (routeName) {
      
          case AtivarEmailPage.route:
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AtivarEmailPage());
            break;
          default:
            return pagesRouteFactories[settings.name]();
            break;
        }
      });

  Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar(context) => BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_filled),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.fitness_center),
            label: 'Treinos',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Pesquisar',
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (routeName) {
          print(pagesRouteFactories.keys.toList()[routeName]);
          navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(
              pagesRouteFactories.keys.toList()[routeName],
              arguments: routeName == 0 ? null : [null, null]);
          onItemTapped(routeName);
        },
        backgroundColor: HexColor("#FFFFFF").withOpacity(0.08),
        selectedItemColor: HexColor("#FFCC80"),
        unselectedItemColor: HexColor("#FFFFFF").withOpacity(0.30),
      );
}
```

**screens:**

**HomeView**

[image]

**AtivarEmail**

[image]

**I would like to go back with the bottomNavigatorBar visible to Homeview after pressing the android back button on the ActivateEmail screen**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so create a static method to handle it from any class.

The short answer is: don't do that.

Read up on [flutter state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options). Pick the one you like best, but don't home-brew a solution.

Comment: thanks, it solved my problem, it's a little more complex, but it's necessary when your project gets bigger

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using mounted in reverse. `mounted` is true when the widget is part of the tree. See [The API documentation](http://%5B1%5D:%20https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html)

Try

```
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() => telaPrincipal.show());
    }
```

instead of `if (!mounted)`

Comment: I can get onWillPop to work, but the BottomNavBar is not visible